# Spring data join query not fetching results in junit

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, junit, spring-data-jpa

I have an SpringBoot application in which I have defined an entity as given below

```
@Entity
public class Organisation {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@JsonIgnore
private Long id;

private String entityId;
private String type;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "organisation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<OrganisationProperty> properties = new HashSet<>();

public Organisation(String entityId, String type,Set<OrganisationProperty> properties) {
    this.entityId = entityId;
    this.type = type;
    properties.forEach(p -> {
        this.properties.add(new OrganisationProperty(p.getPropName(), p.getPropValue()));
    });
}
```

In my service class I have a function to delete the properties

```
public void editOrgType(String orgTypeName, List<OrgHierarchyEditProperty> editProperties) {
Set<OrganisationProperty> orgPropertiesToDelete = organisationPropertyRepository
                    .getOrganisationPropertyByTypeAndPropName(orgTypeName, editProperty.getOldPropName());
organisationPropertyRepository.deleteAll(orgPropertiesToDelete);
```

This function to fetch is defined in the repository class

```
@Query("select p from Organisation o join OrganisationProperty p on o.id = p.organisation.id "
        + "where o.type = ?1 and p.propName = ?2")
public Set<OrganisationProperty> getOrganisationPropertyByTypeAndPropName(String type, String propName);
```

I am testing the same logic through a junit test case

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    Set<OrganisationProperty> circProperties = new HashSet<>();
    OrganisationProperty circProp = new OrganisationProperty("p", "v");
    circProperties.add(circProp);
    Organisation circle = new Organisation("circle1", "circle", circProperties);
    circProp.setOrganisation(circle);
    circle = organisationRepository.save(circle);
}

@Test
public void editOrgTypeAddDeleteTest() {
    List<OrgHierarchyEditProperty> editProperties = new ArrayList<>();
    OrgHierarchyEditProperty delProp = new OrgHierarchyEditProperty();
    delProp.setEditMode(Mode.DELETE);
    delProp.setOldPropName("p");
    editProperties.add(delProp);
    organisationService.editOrgType("circle", editProperties);
    Organisation circle = organisationRepository.findByEntityId("circle1").get();
    boolean deleted = circle.getProperties().stream().anyMatch(p -> p.getPropName().equals("p"));
    assertFalse(deleted);
}
```

When I call the service through controller the logic works fine and the properties get deleted. But from the junit test case the function organisationPropertyRepository.getOrganisationPropertyByTypeAndPropName does not return anything and so the properties to delete "p" is never fetched and deleted. If I do a debug and call organisationPropertyRepository.findAll() inside the service it gets the property "p" but somehow the join query is not working from inside the junit

Comment: Typo in the test? Shouldn't `organisationRepository.findByEntityIdAndActiveInd("circle1", true)` be `organisationRepository.findByEntityIdAndActiveInd("circle", true)`?

Comment: What is that Method `findByEntityIdAndActiveInd` anyway?

Comment: I have corrected the typo and missing entity id in the edit